# Sending a command to a range of IP's using PSEXEC and a Batch file

Tags: batch-file, concatenation, psexec

I'm trying to send an unlock command to remote computers.  All computers are on the same subnet and an upper and lower IP will be provided at run time.

I have constructed the following:

```
:range
echo.
set /a ip=xxx.xxx.xxx
echo Please input lower IP range.
set /p lower=%ip%
echo.
echo Please input upper IP range.
set /p upper=%ip%
set /a lip=
echo.


:loop
set lip = %ip%%lower%
psexec \\%lip% -u .\<redacted> -p <redacted> Net user <redacted> /Active:yes
if %lower%==%upper% goto loopend
set /a lower=%lower%+1
goto loop

:loopend
goto end
```

This gives me a lot of errors.  Firstly, I understood `set lip = %ip%%lower%` would concatenate the two.  I'm not certain they are being processed as strings, however.  How can this be resolved?

If I echo `%ip%` I only see the first part of the IP (before the first .).  Clearly this data isn't being stored correctly.  I tried enclosing it in speech marks with no success (it says Missing operator).

I am open to any radically different solutions if you feel I am making a pigs ear of this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add a `.` between the parts of your IP address.

```
set lip=%ip%.%lower%
```

You can add an `ECHO` statement right after the above line to make sure the IP looks right.

```
ECHO %lip%
```

**UPDATE**

You also need to remove the `/a` from this line:

```
set /a ip=xxx.xxx.xxx
```

It should just be:

```
set ip=xxx.xxx.xxx
```

Comment: On doing this, I get `ECHO is off.` from the line `echo %lip%`

Comment: You need to remove the spaces you have before and after the `=` sign.

Comment: Ugh, yes.  I did this all other places.  Missed that one.  I still return "128" when I echo %ip%, however.

Comment: That was it, knew I was close.  ty!